# Reading and writing java.util.ArrayList from Parcelable class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, android-intent, parcelable

I'm using `Parcelable` class to send `Object` from one activity to another activity in Android Java.

Parcelable only implements for me `String` data.

How I can read and write `productsArrayList` and `status` from this class?

```
public class Bill implements Parcelable {
    private String id;
    private Date createAt;
    private ArrayList<Products> productsArrayList;
    private ArrayList<StatusBill> status;

    public Bill(String id, Date createAt, ArrayList<Products> productsArrayList, ArrayList<StatusBill> status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.createAt = createAt;
        this.productsArrayList = productsArrayList;
        this.status = status;
    }

    protected Bill(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        createAt = new Date(in.readLong());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeLong(createAt.getTime());
    }
    public static final Creator<Bill> CREATOR = new Creator<Bill>() {
        @Override
        public Bill createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Bill(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Bill[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Bill[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parcel List of List of Parcelable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562711/parcel-list-of-list-of-parcelable-object)

Comment: @PeterO. Sorry, it doesn't work for my situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for all case when using `Parcelable` class

This website helps you to implement a `Custom` class to `Parcelable` class

Paste your `Custom` class in textarea and click `Build` button.

You will receive your `Custom` class implemnets `Parcelable` class

http://www.parcelabler.com/

Comment: There would have been another solution: serialize the list to a JSON string.